# Redshift slow COPY command

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

I have a bunch of data (100 columns and around 30M rows) Im looking to copy from S3. Its crazy slow -3-4 hours to copy.I have a dist key and sort keys defined on the target table.
Im wondering what should I be looking into to speed up the copy?
Im using a ra3.xplus with 1 node.

This is the schema:

```
CREATE  TABLE curation.customer_transaction_v2 (
    uuid varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    custid varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    is_cancelled bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    transaction_amount_usd numeric(17, 2) NULL,
    transaction_amount numeric(17, 2) NULL,
    transaction_date date NULL,
    system_of_record text NULL,
    is_reseller bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    is_in_production bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    created_on timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_on timestamptz NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created_by text NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_USER,
    updated_by text NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_USER,
    supplier_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    oem_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    vendor_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    unique_id text NULL,
    cxo_legacy_unique_id text NULL,
    cxo_status_code text NULL DEFAULT 'new'::text,
    batch_part_id int8 NULL,
    batchid int4 NULL,
    transaction_description varchar(1000) NULL,
    deployed_to_incight timestamptz NULL,
    deployed_to_borg timestamptz NULL,
    transaction_type text NOT NULL,
    business_unit text NULL,
    source_entity text NULL,
    line_item_amount_usd numeric(17, 2) NULL,
    custid_fully_qualified text NULL,
    additional_description varchar(1000) NULL,
    approval_status text NULL,
    approver text NULL,
    cost_center_code varchar(1000) NULL,
    cost_center_name varchar(1000)NULL,
    cost_center_parent_code varchar(1000) NULL,
    currency_code text NULL,
    conversion_rate numeric NULL,
    cxo_product_description varchar(1000) NULL,
    cxo_product_id int8 NULL,
    department_code text NULL,
    department_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    discount_amount numeric NULL,
    expense_type text NULL,
    gl_code varchar(1000) NULL,
    gl_name text NULL,
    gl_posting_date date NULL,
    invoice_id text NULL,
    invoice_line_item_id text NULL,
    invoiced_line_item_amount numeric NULL,
    line_item_amount numeric NULL,
    line_item_description varchar(65535) NULL,
    line_item_discount_amount numeric NULL,
    line_item_id text NULL,
    line_item_product_part_number text NULL,
    line_item_quantity numeric NULL,
    line_item_tax_amount numeric NULL,
    line_item_unit_of_measure text NULL,
    line_item_unit_price numeric NULL,
    po_id text NULL,
    po_line_item_id text NULL,
    requisition_line_item_id text NULL,
    requisition_id text NULL,
    shipping_amount numeric NULL,
    submitter text NULL,
    tax_amount numeric NULL,
    total_amount numeric NULL,
    vendor_identifier varchar(65535) NULL,
    vendor_name varchar(65535) NULL,
    document_date date NULL,
    document_id varchar(65535) NULL,
    document_description varchar(65535) NULL,
    transaction_vendor_name varchar(65535) NULL,
    paid_date date NULL,
    manufacturer_name varchar(65535) NULL,
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    cxo_product_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    closest_supplier_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    closest_oem_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    import_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    product_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    curation_stale bool NULL DEFAULT true,
    finalized bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    invoice_due_date date NULL,
    training_text varchar(1000) NULL,
    custom_fields super NULL,
    cxo_duplicate_check_field varchar(1000) NULL,
    cxo_notes varchar(1000) NULL,
    force_recalc bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    is_date_null bool NULL,
    is_date_bad_range bool NULL,
    is_date_in_error bool NULL,
    import_file_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    transaction_vendor_identifier varchar(65535) NULL,
    training_text_hash text NULL,
    cancel_reason text NULL,
    generated_description varchar(1000) NULL,
    generated_vendor_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    generated_vendor_short_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    closest_supplier_confidence_level numeric NULL,
    closest_oem_confidence_level numeric NULL,
    partner_reseller_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    partner_reseller_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    end_customer_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    end_customer_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    unspsc_product_code varchar(1000) NULL,
    line_item_product_sku varchar(1000) NULL,
    generated_end_customer_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    generated_partner_reseller_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    closest_end_customer_confidence_level numeric NULL,
    closest_partner_reseller_confidence_level numeric NULL,
    closest_end_customer_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    closest_partner_reseller_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    distributor_name varchar(1000) NULL,
    generated_description_hash varchar(1000) NULL,
    cxo_category_override bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    client_category_override bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    client_oem_override bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    client_oem_override_reason varchar(1000) NULL,
    cxo_oem_override bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    cxo_oem_override_reason varchar(1000) NULL,
    client_category_override_reason varchar(1000) NULL,
    cxo_category_override_reason varchar(1000) NULL,
    pickle_id text NULL,
    pii_individual_line_item_description_flag varchar NULL,
    line_item_description_deidentified varchar NULL,
    pii_individual_supplier_short_name_flag varchar NULL,
    pii_individual_oem_short_name_flag varchar NULL,
    marketplace_uuid varchar(100) NULL,
    channel_partner_uuid varchar(100) null
    )
    DISTSTYLE KEY
 DISTKEY (custid)
 SORTKEY (
    custid
    , document_date
    , paid_date
    , gl_posting_date
    )
```

```
I use the following copy:
COPY curation.customer_transaction_v2
FROM 's3://<bucket>customer_transaction_2'
CREDENTIALS '<>'
CSV DELIMITER ','
```

I have split files usig the column "batch_id" for distributed copy

Comment: "Its crazy slow -3-4 hours to copy" - how have you determined that it's slow? What part of the process is the bottleneck? I/O ?  building the table?

Comment: good point...I dont know if this is the limit but Im wondering what can I do to potentially speed it up?

Comment: Should I not define  distribution/ sort keys right away and just load into  a temp table?

Comment: Not sure if it's needed on modern RA3 instances, but in the old days people used to scale-out and add extra nodes for large migrations, then scale-in again afterwards. Is this **just one table?**

Comment: Yes just one table...

Comment: Check that your table distribution isn’t set to all before the copy. Or switch to spectrum might be easier

Comment: @user433342  : read the table schema. The diststyle is NOT all.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to think about:

- your SORT key is possibly too wide
- **define your SORT key *AFTER* performing the load (using an intermediate temp table without a SORT key defined)**
- add compression to all the columns where it makes sense to do so (people often overlook this)

This might be of interest: https://repost.aws/articles/ARfMxfvwcqRMummPCJLfrsHA/best-practices-for-loading-electronic-health-claims-data-to-amazon-redshift

A **ra3.xlplus** instance has an upper I/O limit of around 0.65GB/sec, equivalent to approximately 2.3 TB per hour, which gives you a loose upper bound on load speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch.  You say 'I have split files usig (sic) the column "batch_id" for distributed copy'.  Does this mean that you have many files in S3?  Like 10,000 plus files? 100,000?

If this is the case then you have run into an S3 anti-pattern.  S3 is an object store and as such each file is stored based on a hash.  Each file can be stored in a different place from a file that "looks like" it should be right next door.  This means that each file lookup takes time - like .75 sec.

If the files are small, like 100kb, then the transfer time is way less than the lookup time and everything runs real slow.  The smaller the files, the more there are, and the slower things go.

Not sure this matches what you have going on but if so you need fewer, bigger files.  Like 1GB big or at least 100MB.

BTW if this is what you have going on, splitting the files by the eventual distribution key has no benefit as COPY assigns files to read to the slices in a round robin.  If my hunch is off the mark then carry on.

Comment: Hey so its around 400 files...some are a few kb and some are a few GB. 
Unfortunately unloading this again will be painful @Bill Weiner

Comment: sorry correction...the files are between 1MB-2 GB

Comment: 400 files isn't enough to cause the times you are seeing.  The node you have only has 2 slices, so 2 files can be read at the same time.  So object lookup should contribute only a few minutes to the copy.  Each 2GB file should be transferred across the network in less than 2.5min assuming that the bucket is in the same region as the redshift cluster.  I figure you should be able to move 300GB+ to RS in 3.5 hours. Is this about your data size? Is there an ec2 gateway between RS and S3 acting as a bottleneck?

Comment: @ Bill weiner Removing the sort keys made my upload faster(done in 20 mins)

Comment: Ah. When the target table is empty (new) and this will cause Redshift to sort the rows when inserting.  It sounds like the cluster is spending its time sorting the data during the COPY.  Does this match what you are seeing during execution.  The downside is that Redshift query performance can be dramatically faster if the table is properly sorted.